# Unwanted automatic formatting in Lync 2010

Tags: hyperlink, emoticons, lync-2010

I would like to type a file path or URL into Lync 2010 without it being converted to a hyperlink, and I would like to be able to use punctuation without it unexpectedly getting converted to emoticons.

For example, if I send: **Type this: mount \\server\folder K:**, Lync automatically mangles it as **Type this: mount \\server\folder (File:\\server\folder) K:** when it reaches the recipient. I was trying to tell the recipient an exact string to type, but it is no longer valid once Lync adds the hyperlink.

If I backspace at the end of the underlined (hyperlink) text before sending it, Lync will remove the hyperlink.  However, sometimes it keeps coming back as soon as I move the cursor after removing the hyperlink.

Likewise, if I send the message: "**Put a colon (:) after the drive letter**", Lync replaces **(:)** with **(** plus a **smiley-face**.  Very annoying!!

I realize you can suppress emoticons on the sender's end, but I would really prefer that the text not be mangled when it reaches the recipient.

Is there any way to suppress this automatic reformatting of my text, and make Lync simply send the literal text I typed?

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble sending a URL to a co-worker. Asking him to turn off emoticons (uncheck the box at "Tools->Options->General->Show emoticons in messages") did the trick for that.

Comment: it stop working now with Lync 2016

Comment: My corp recently upgraded to Lync/Skype 2016 and the setting there is in "Tools->Options->IM->Show emoticons in messages". I tested it a little and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could technically copy and when instead of doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, right click and select "Paste Unformatted".

Comment: Strangely this doesn't keep lync from formatting a path like 'C:\Program Files\' as a link